# iPad simulator network traffic does NOT go through system proxy

Tags: iphone, ios, proxy, ipad

Is anyone aware of a reason that system proxy settings (via System Preferences) would be ineffective on the iPad simulator for iOS 4.2?

Googling so far has turned up the fact that perhaps under old versions of the iOS SDK, it circumvented the system proxy, but I can't find a consensus about the current state of things.

I can't seem to get ANY http requests to get diverted to my proxy.

Thanks very much.

EDIT: nothing done to system settings changes this; NO traffic will go through the proxy server

Answer (score -1):

Whether an application uses the system proxy settings depends on how each individual application in implemented.  Apple is on-again and off-again with whether the simulator will use the system proxy settings.  I'd open a bug with Apple.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this relates to the question asked – the asker isn't doing anything strange with the _simulator's_ network settings, just the Mac's.